# SQL query multiple sum not totalling

Tags: sql, join, sum

I am new to SQL. I am querying 5 tables from Fishbowl Inventory system for an iReport. The tables are: SO, SOITEM, SOITEMSTATUS, CUSTOMER, SOSTATUS, and CARRIER.

The query should provide one line for each SOITEM.SOID with a SUM of QTYTOFULFILL.
When I run my query, SOITEM.SOID shows multiple line items - each with a qtytofulfill. My query is not summing the field 'QTYTOFULFILL' and providing one total as expected.

The query is:

```
SELECT Distinct
     so.num, so.id, so.shiptoname, so.vendorpo, so.customerpo, customer.name,  soitem.statusid, soitem.qtytofulfill, soitem.qtyfulfilled, sostatus.id, sostatus.name, soitem.datescheduledfulfillment,carrier.id, so.carrierid, soitemstatus.id, carrier.name as carrier
from SO
inner Join Customer
ON so.customerid = customer.id
Join
soitem
On so.id = soitem.soid
Join (Select sum(soitem.qtytofulfill) as "Cases" From soitem Group by soitem.soid)
ON (soitem.soid = so.id)
inner Join sostatus
On soitem.statusid = sostatus.id
Inner Join soitemstatus
ON soitemstatus.id = soitem.statusid
Inner join carrier
on carrier.id = so.carrierid
where soitemstatus.id IN ('10', '11', '12', '14', '20', '30', '40');
```

Query does not throw an error - I get valid data - just no sum as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks. BC

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: You have to add `"Cases"` to the select list in order for it to appear in the result.

Comment: I will help if you tag your question with the database platform your are using, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc?